# Why is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I'm referring to [this](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/219/are-there-any-cultures-with-no-known-interactions-that-have-notable-similarities) question, which is now closed as *Too Broad*. I think this should be discussed, since I myself cannot decide whether it is too broad or not and some users seem to have cast reopen votes. How should we treat this now and similar posts in the future?

**EDIT:** As of now, this question has been reopened, but my question still stands.

Comment: The "any" in the question makes it a bit broad, but it is technically answerable by a single example. What makes the question difficult to answer however is the fact that it is difficult to prove the *absence* of any cultural interactions between two cultures but that's another issue.

Comment: By cultural interactions I mean recorded historical events and not just people visiting etc. Maybe I should add this part in my question to remove the broad factor

Comment: Thinking about whether or not this question is too broad gave me the idea to post [this hopefully-slightly-less-broad question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/441/are-there-any-apocalypse-myths-other-than-ragnarok-in-which-some-people-survive). Seeing if people have the same reaction to this one might help us figure out where to draw the line.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a funny/weird one. I'll quote the central question:

> But are there any occurrence of two different cultures having similarities in their mythologies but no known interactions by which they could have transferred their mythologies to each other?

There are many pairs of cultures with similar mythologies, but rather few that never interacted with each other. I can't think of any. So, while this question seems too broad, a comprehensive answer would likely be small.

I think that there are other issues which cloud the issue (ha):

- "similar" with respect to mythologies isn't clarified
- same issue with "no known interactions" (this has since been clarified though)
- It would be hard to have a comprehensive answer, so there would probably be multiple partial answers

Now, if the question were about whole mythologies, and especially if "similar" was clarified, then I would err on the side of ***not* too broad**. However, the question title also narrows the scope to "creation myths"...which, ironically enough, makes this **too broad**. Creation myths (and Flood myths) tend to be surprisingly similar.

**My verdict:** I have voted to close this question as "too broad" ***pending*** clarification of "similar".